# I need to put constraint on a data packet which should not cross 4k boundary

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I am trying to write a constraint for a data packet in system verilog. I have a data packet whose size can be 0-4096 bits and I need to write a constraint in my packet class in a way that packet should be 4 byte aligned and it should not cross 4k boundary or if the start address is above 4k, it should not cross 8k boundary, and so on upto 1GB. So, the issue is that I can write a constraint for the first 4k boundary as below (if it looks fine ?) but this won't be true if the start address is above 4K and in that case it should not cross 8K or if start address is above 8K, so on, how can I write a generic constraint for the same ??

```
class packet
int size;
rand bit    [31:0]  addr;        // start address
rand bit    [7:0]   data[]; // data 
rand bit    [15:0]  size;                //  size of packet

constraint size_c     { size inside [0:4096]; }
constraint addr_c     { addr[0:1]==0; // for 4 byte alignment
                        addr[12:0] <'h1000 - size; }

endclass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're almost there. I think you meant:

```
addr[11:0] + size <= 32'h1000 ;
```

I would recommend **not** using *unsized literals*, ie I would recommend saying `32'h1000` not `'h1000`. This is because the behaviour of such literals changed between Verilog-1995 and Verilog-2001, so it's probably best to just avoid them.

---

```
module M;

  class packet;
    rand bit    [13:0]  addr;        // start address
    rand bit    [15:0]  size;        //  size of packet

    constraint size_c     { size inside {[1:4096]}; }
    constraint addr_c     { addr[1:0]==0; // for 4 byte alignment
                            addr[11:0] + size <= 32'h1000; }
  endclass

  initial
    begin
      packet p = new;
      repeat (10)
        begin
          p.randomize;
          $display("%p - %d", p, p.addr[11:0] + p.size);
        end
    end

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3gtq